# List objects from different class in Java

Tags: java, list, class, inheritance, arraylist

Assuming I have following classes:

```
class B extends A
class C extends A
class D extends B
```

List:

```
List<A> mylist,
```

And objects from different class:

```
A b = new B();
A c = new C();
B d = new D();
B b2 = new B();
```

Which of the following is correct? And why?

```
mylist.add(b);
mylist.add(c);
mylist.add(d);
mylist.add(b2);
```

What is the difference between these two way of declare: B b2 = new B() and A b = new B();

The reference type of object b and c are A, so I think these two lines of code are correct,  am I right? What about the other two?

The reason I ask this question is because I want to implement this function:

```
//calculate method in different class will do different calculation.
class A{
    int calculate(int parameter1, int parameter2){
        return parameter1*parameter2;
    }
}
class B extends A{
    int calculate(int parameter1, int parameter2){
        return parameter1+parameter2;
    }
}
class C extends A{
    int calculate(int parameter1, int parameter2){
        return parameter1-parameter2;
    }
}
class D extends B{
    int calculate(int parameter1, int parameter2){
        return parameter1/parameter2;
    }
}

A b = new B();
A c = new C();
B d = new D();
B b2 = new B();

List<A> mylist;
mylist.add(b);
mylist.add(c);
mylist.add(d);
mylist.add(b2);
// TODO hundreds of objects from subclass of A are added into this list

Iterator<A> iterator = mylist.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(iterator.calculate(2,1));
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by correct? Like compileable?

Comment: As others have said, all of these will compile. Keep in mind though, when using the objects in the list, you'll only have an `A` reference to them unless you perform instanceof checks and cast to the subclasses.

Comment: Yes, if it is compilable. And also if it is a good way to implement this function. Like I need to call the override method with same name of those objects from different classes. Any risk?

Comment: @DanTemple So even if I declared     B b2 = new B();    , the reference type of b2 is A?

Comment: @JLan If you pull it from the list of `A`, yes. So think about this: `List<A. list = new ArrayList<A>(); list.add(new B()); A obj = list.get(0);` So `obj` would need to be cast in order for it to be treated as a B.

Comment: @JLan Looking at your other comment though, you want to call the overridden method on the subclass, that will work with your `A` reference as long as the overridden method exists on `A` and the one you want will be called. Look at this [ideone link](https://ideone.com/BWGw69) that should hopefully explain that a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

They're all correct, since they're all subclasses of A.

Comment: So is that means no matter what the reference type the object is when it was declared, I only need to make sure the 'real' type of this object is from a class extend from A, B or C?

Comment: Not exactly. If you have `A example = new B()` and you have `List<B> lst`, then you can't add `example` to `lst`. So the reference type does matter. You would have to downcast `example` in order to add it to a list of `B`.

Comment: You need to think of it conceptually. For example, if you have a list of cars, you can add a Volvo to a list of cars, but you can't add a car to a list of Volvos.

Comment: I mean like b2(reference type is B) and b(reference type is A), they can be added to List<A> because the 'real' type is a subclass of A. So what is the difference of B b2 = new B() and A b = new B();

Comment: Both reference type and object type matter here. See my counterexample above

Answer (score 1):

All of these classes extend `A`, either directly or indirectly, therefore all their instances can be added to a `List<A>` instance.

What exactly is it that you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

As `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` can all be reference-cast to `A`, and `myList` is mandated to contain `A` references, all of your examples will successfully be added to the list.